# Loading Trained ResNet 50 network on Tensorflow in Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, resnet

I recently started working on Deep Learning. I need to run a pre trained ResNet50 Network loaded using Tensorflow on Windows CPU. I do not find a structured way to do it anywhere online. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, questions which ask us to find an external source as an answer may be put on hold as they attract opinionated answers, and they may only be useful for the current poster.

The best way to find an answer to these questions is to do some preliminary research and get more understanding of what constitutes deep learning and resnet50 network.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the official "How to do Transfer Learning" tutorial from tensorflow website. https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining

The thing that you have to change is on `retrain.py` line 1302, it will load the pre-trained model from tensorflow-hub :

```
default=(
          'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1'),
```

to this :

```
default=(
          'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/feature_vector/1'),
```

Or you can check the other pre-trained model list on this website :
https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-feature-vector